# automatic delete of mysql table data after 2 minutes

Tags: php, mysql

the query is not executed i don't know why

here is my try

i use this code to delete login attempts record and ip  from the tabel after 2 min to allow user to try login again

if another soultion is better than this please submit it

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
    <meta name="author" content="gencyolcu" />

    <title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>
<style>
.fall
{
    background-color: aliceblue;
    color: darkkhaki;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 200px;
    padding: 200px;
    margin-left: 200px;
}
#txt
{
    font-family: fantasy;
    font-size: xx-large;
    font-style: italic;
}
</style>
<body>

<div class="fall">
 <p id="txt">You have exceeded the allowed  login times try again 
</p>
</div>
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("register_form", $con);


mysql_query("DELETE FROM login_attempts WHERE time < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 minutes");

mysql_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, first step to fixing the problem would be to get the MySQL error. Right before you close the connection, `echo mysql_error();` - this in its self might help you solve your issue.

Comment: Why are you deleting from the login attempts table? Can't you get a similar result if you just limit how far back you check the login attempts table? Seems if you just query the that last 2 minutes of the table you can keep the old records and know if someone is trying to loginto many accounts.

Comment: It's not a <= situation is it?  You're not trying EXACTLY at 2 minutes out?  What happens if you `select * from login_attempts where time < Now() - INTERVAL 2 minutes`? directly against the DB?

Answer (score 1):

Try this (MINUTE instead of MINUTES):

```
sql_query("DELETE FROM login_attempts WHERE time < NOW() -  INTERVAL 2 MINUTE");
```

Comment: Beat me to it.  See here for the domain of values for `INTERVAL`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Comment: @Valdogg21 Take a look at date_sub definition: `DATE_SUB(date,INTERVAL expr unit)`. expr (second column in table you refer to) here is 2 and unit (first column) is MINUTE . And I have tested that expression before posting it here.

Comment: @TheSniper104 what type of data do you have for time column? Timestamp or datetime?

Comment: Also, how do you know it is not working? try to connect to database with PhpMyAdmin/HedySQL or something like that and execute your query.

Comment: @FAngel I was just adding the link so OP could see other possible values, not questioning your syntax :)

Comment: @Valdogg21 oops. Sorry, I misunderstood you ) Anyway, additional explanation will not harm.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your syntax is wrong.

Try replacing MINUTES by MINUTE

"DELETE FROM login_attempts WHERE time < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 **MINUTE**"

If it doesnt help, post here your MySQL error.

Hope it helps.